# Reference a variable within a variable in JMeter

Tags: variables, jmeter

I'm working with JMeter. I'd like to specify the test host using user defined variables, like this:

```
variable name       value  
localhost           localhost  
test                192.168.0.1
hostname            ${localhost}
```

Executing the test, I see that the hostname value is not substituted, and obviously the test fails. I know I can use properties and pass the hostname from the command line, or simply change the hostname value. Is it possible to it like I've explained?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. I've changed the hostname variable value to: `${__evalVar(${localhost})}`, but I've got this error:

> ERRROR jmeter.functions.EvalVarFunction: Variables have not yet been defined

So I've moved the hostname variable declaration in a "User defined variable" child node of my Sampler node. That solved it.

Comment: Fine that you solved this by yourself. One note: [all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are processed at the start](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables), so I could also simply use 2 _consequent_ separate UDV and define in 1st 'localhost' var and in the 2nd - 'hostname' in the way you did.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about this approach. I like it.

Answer (score 9):

To solve this you should use hostname = ${__eval(${localhost})}
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval 
Carlos' answer has a mistake (which I can't comment on due to rep) as it uses evalVar, this requires as an argument a plain string:

> This works: ${__evalVar(localhost)})
>      This works: ${__eval(${localhost})}
>      This doesn't work (the current answer): ${__evalVar(${localhost})}
>   http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__evalVar

Comment: Tiny thing, but it looks like you have an extra right parenthesis at the end of 
`This works: ${__evalVar(localhost)})`.

Answer (score 2):

Check this forum:
[from Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables/)

For example: getting value of varible "listid_XXX" where the XXX number comes from an index variable:

```
${__V(listid_${idx1})}
```

Answer (score 0):

New newer versions (from 2.2), you can use `${__V(${...})}/`.

Ex: `${__V(${SERVER_CONTEXT})}/rest`

As @Alies Belik mentioned, if you get

```
ERRROR jmeter.functions.EvalVarFunction: Variables have not yet been defined
```

then define the 2nd variable in next other UDV (User Defined Variables) node.